# Leitura de dados SQL sem NOLOCK

Tags: sql, commit

Tenho uma Stored Procedure (SQL Server) que é acessada por diversas aplicações concomitantemente em intervalos menores que 1 minuto. Ela foi construída utilizando **NOLOCK** em seus acessos, muito provavelmente para ganhar em velocidade. Porém, a leitura de dados não persistidos está trazendo problemas no processamento lógico da aplicação e será necessário alterar essa **Stored Procedure**.

Minha dúvida é em relação ao comportamento das inúmeras aplicações que utilizam essa **Stored Procedure**, quando isso for alterado. Haverá queda de performance? Se o acesso for feito enquanto um dado ainda está sendo persistido a aplicação ficará em fila, perdendo tempo de **I/O**, até que o dado seja persistido?

Comment: Obviamente que sim, o `NOLOCK` justamente serve para evitar a necessidade de aguardar dados persistidos.

Comment: Sim, as requisições ficarão enfileiradas e cada requisição só será liberada quando a(s) tabela(s) envolvida(s) for(em) liberada(s). Você terá que avaliar se este tempo de espera poderá comprometer sua aplicação.

Comment: Okay. Neste cenário, um SELECT concorre com outro? Digo, enquanto a proc está executando a requisição de uma aplicação, uma segunda aplicação fica em fila aguardando o fim da primeira?

Comment: Veja: https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/statements/set-transaction-isolation-level-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017